# Using Perl on Windows, how can I ensure I get the path in the correct case following a chdir?

Tags: windows, perl, path, case-sensitive, cwd

Consider the following code:

```
print cwd . "\n";
$str= "../source"; # note the lower case 's'    
chdir($str);
print cwd . "\n";
```

If my current directory is `c:\parentdir\Source` (note the capital 'S'), the output of this will be:

```
c:/parentdir/Source
c:/parentdir/source
```

This causes problems in a subroutine of mine that cares about the correct case of folder names. $str is passed in to my subroutine, so I can't know ahead of time whether it has the correct case. How do I determine the case-correct name of a path that matches `$str`?

More detail here:

- I realize that `../source` is a pathological example, but it serves to
  illustrate the problem. It occurs even if `$str` is requesting a
  folder other than the current one.
- I have tried numerous options, including `rel2abs`, a glob search on
  `$str`, and others, but they all seem to return "`source`" instead of
  "`Source`".
- I could search `$str/..` for all directories, convert them all to
  absolute paths and compare them to an absolute path version of `$str`,
  but that seems like a hack. I was hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: It's not incorrect. Usually Windows filesystems are case-insenstive, unless NTFS is configured otherwise.

Comment: Absolutely true. Unfortunately, my subroutine needs the correct case for reasons other than simply manipulating the file system. So, while Windows and Perl don't care, I unfortunately have to.

Comment: Case-insensitive, yes, but it is also *case-preserving*. If a file is created as `Foo`, it can be accessed using `foo`, but the system knows its name is `Foo`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings; use strict;
use Cwd;
use File::Spec::Functions qw( canonpath );
use Win32;

print canonpath( cwd ), "\n";

chdir '../source';

print canonpath( cwd ), "\n";

print canonpath( Win32::GetLongPathName( cwd ) ), "\n";
```

```
C:\DOCUME~1\...\LOCALS~1\Temp\t\Source> t
C:\DOCUME~1\...\LOCALS~1\Temp\t\Source
C:\DOCUME~1\...\LOCALS~1\Temp\t\source
C:\Documents and Settings\...\Local Settings\Temp\t\Source
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks to me like I don't even need canonpath. If I issue the following: $str = Win32::GetLongPathName($str);, then it seems to change to the correct case, even if $str specifies a relative path.

Comment: `canonpath` is just to get Windows style slashes in paths in case that mattered.

Answer (score 0):

I use cygwin and svn, and I found this question when svn couldn't find that the files because it was case sensitive

e.g.
$ cd /cygdrive/c/svn/delphi2010/lib/checksum   # not the true case

$ svn ls
svn: warning: W155010: The node '/cygdrive/c/svn/delphi2010/lib/checksum' was not found.
svn: E200009: Could not list all targets because some targets don't exist

$ eval cd $( cygpath $( perl -le 'use Win32; $d=`cygpath -aw .`; chomp($d); print Win32::GetLongPathName($d)' ) )

$ pwd
/cygdrive/c/svn/Delphi2010/lib/CheckSum  # note the case is restored

## and svn ls works again!